# Random publishing twitter images from directory

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

So i do not know what my exact problem is, i am an amateur programmer so i dont wholly know if i'm doing right or wrong. That's why I would really appreciate if anyone could help me just a bit. 
This is my code and I don't really know what i'm failing at cause it says it's a failure on the path:

```
import tweepy
from time import sleep
folderpath= "E:\Fotosprueba"
def tweepy_creds():
    consumer_key = 'x'
    consumer_secret = 'x'
    access_token = 'x'
    access_token_secret = 'x'

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    return tweepy.API(auth)

def getPathsFromDir(dir, EXTS="extensions=,png,jpg,jpeg,gif,tif,tiff,tga,bmp"):
    return this.listPaths('E:\Fotosprueba', EXTS)

def tweet_photos(api):
imagePaths = "E:\Fotosprueba"
for x in imagePaths:
    status = "eeeee macarena"
    try:
        api.update_with_media(filename=x,status=status)
        print ("Tweeted!")
        sleep(10)
    except Exception as e:
        print ("encountered error! error deets: %s"%str(e))
        break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tweet_photos(tweepy_creds())
```

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting and where is it occurring (you'll be able to see this from the Traceback, if there is one), and what's the expected behaviour?

Comment: encountered error! error deets: Unable to access file: El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado     @Hoppeduppeanut the result should be tweeting in my account diferent images i have in the folder i specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be missing indentation on your `tweet_photos` method. Without this indentation, the interpreter won't be able to tell where the method starts and ends.

Additionally, you are attempting to iterate over a `str`. In this case, the value of `x` will be each individual character in this string. You can verify this by running the following code in the Python interpreter:

```
imagePaths = "E:\Fotosprueba"
for x in imagePaths:
  print(x)
```

Output:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
E
:
\
F
o
t
o
s
p
r
u
e
b
a
```

By the looks of things, you may want to pass the value of this str to the `getPathsFromDir` method instead. Try this:

```
def getPathsFromDir(dir, EXTS="extensions=,png,jpg,jpeg,gif,tif,tiff,tga,bmp"):
    return this.listPaths(dir, EXTS) # This now uses the value of dir


def tweet_photos(api):
    imagePaths = "E:\Fotosprueba"
    # This now passes imagepaths to the getPathsFromDir method, 
    # and *should* return a list of files.
    for x in getPathsFromDir(imagePaths): 
        status = "eeeee macarena"
        try:
            api.update_with_media(filename=x,status=status)
            print ("Tweeted!")
            sleep(10)
        except Exception as e:
            print ("encountered error! error deets: %s"%str(e))
            break
```

In theory this should work as intended, as long as your class also includes a `listPaths` method. If it doesn't, you'll need to modify to include this method, or change the call to `this.listpaths` to point to somewhere else.

Comment: it totally worked now that's just right what i was looking for. Genious! Thank you so much!